# Replacing Pager Data in RecyclerView

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, android-paging

I have a fragment that is the profile page of the user. The profile page will display the user's posts, however, there's another button on that page that will display which posts the user has liked.

ProfileFragment:

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

//Call the function to get the profile posts
viewModel.getProfilePosts(profileId)

//Set the post adapter
val adapter = PostAdapter(this)

//Collect and submit posts to adapter for viewing
viewLifecycleOwner.lifecycleScope.launch {
    viewModel.profilePosts.collect {
        adapter.submitData(it)
    }
  }
}
```

This works well and does show the posts when the view is created. The complexity arises when I try to add an event listener to the button to view the user's likes and when the button is clicked this function is called:

```
private fun getProfileLikesPosts(profileId: Int) {
    viewModel.getProfileLikes(profileId)
}
```

I tried adding this coroutine scope inside the onViewCreated, but what it does is it doesn't show the user's posts when I navigate to their profile, however, when I click on their likes it does show their likes.

```
viewLifecycleOwner.lifecycleScope.launch {
    viewModel.profileLikedPosts.collect {
        adapter.submitData(it)
    }
}
```

Here's how the data looks like in my view model:

```
private val _profileLikedPosts =
    MutableStateFlow<PagingData<PostResponse>>(PagingData.empty())
val profileLikedPosts = _profileLikedPosts
```

How the function is called:

```
fun getProfileLikes(profileId: Int) {
    viewModelScope.launch {
        repository.getProfileLikedPosts(profileId).cachedIn(viewModelScope).collect {
            _profileLikedPosts.value = it
        }
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong? How can show the user's posts upon landing, but show the user's likes when the button is clicked?

Comment: your view model is cleared anywhere?

Comment: @sasikumar no it's not

Comment: what is the problem? your api is not calling or recyclerview not updated?